# XSLT - match when value exists in list or array

Tags: xml, xslt

I have several giant books and I want to pull out specific items based on a list of ID values. Is the value in the array? If so, copy, if not ignore.

Seems so basic there should be an answer somewhere, but every post seems far more convoluted. I've tried this various different ways and I can't seem to get it to work: parameter, variable, using exsl:node-set (which I'm unfamiliar with apart from SO answers to similar yet more complicated questions).

**Input XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sec xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
   <title>Section Title</title>
   <fig id="img01">
      <caption><title>Image 1</title></caption>
      <graphic xlink:href="img01.eps"/>
   </fig>

   <fig id="img02">
      <caption><title>Image 2</title></caption>
      <graphic xlink:href="img02.eps"/>
   </fig>
</sec>
```

**Input list of images**
img02, img12, img23, img34, etc...

**Desired Output XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sec xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
   <title>Section Title</title>
   <fig id="img02">
      <caption><title>Image 2</title></caption>
      <graphic xlink:href="img02.eps"/>
   </fig>
</sec>
```

XSLT Sample

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" exclude-result-prefixes="exsl" version="2">

    <xsl:param name="ListOfImages" as="element()">
        <item>img02</item>
        <item>hundreds-of-image-IDs</item>
    </xsl:param>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <sec>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </sec>

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="fig[exsl:node-set($ListOfImages)/item = exsl:node-set(@id)]">
        <p>Image Name: <xsl:value-of select="@id"/></p>
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: What is your XSLT processor and its conformance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, or 4.0.?

Comment: 1.  Please state which version of XSLT your processor supports.  Your stylesheet says `version="2"` but `exsl:node-set()` is a purely XSLT 1.0 feature.  -- 2. Can the list of IDs be hard-coded into the stylesheet? If not, how will you pass it to the stylesheet? -- Hint: use a [**key**](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#key) to select the matching images.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky  I'm using Saxon-PE 9.8.0.12

Comment: @michael.hor257k - I'm using Saxon-PE 9.8.0.12. I didn't realize it was a 1.0 feature, that's probably why it's been quite ineffective. The IDs can be hard-coded into the stylesheet (as I did above), I just run a regex on the list to make it look whatever way is needed. Putting it in a separate file would be a step beyond just matching them at this point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use a list of ids as a parameter e.g.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">
  
  <xsl:param name="id-list" as="xs:string*" select="'img02', 'img12', 'img23'"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="fig[not(@id = $id-list)]"/>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Saxon 9.8 supports XSLT 3.

Comment: I had to drop as="xs:string" to get it to work. Once I took off that attribute I could even make it a node like I did before. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example showing how you could do this in **XSLT 2.0**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="fig-by-id" match="fig" use="@id" />

<xsl:param name="ListOfImages">
    <item>img02</item>
    <item>hundreds-of-image-IDs</item>
</xsl:param>

<xsl:template match="/sec">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="title"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="key('fig-by-id', $ListOfImages/item)"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Note that if you wanted, you could supply the IDs as a comma (or any other delimiter)-separated list and use the `tokenize()` function to create the 2nd parameter used in the `key()` function - e.g.:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="a"/>

<xsl:key name="fig-by-id" match="fig" use="@id" />

<xsl:param name="ListOfImages">img01,img02,img05</xsl:param>

<xsl:template match="/sec">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="title"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="key('fig-by-id', tokenize($ListOfImages, ','))"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```